# Difference in graph and library parameters after relay.build_module.build() in the TVM library

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tvm

In the TVM library, when the `_relay.build_module.build()_` is used, what is the output result both after `relay.build` and `tvm.build`

And what is the difference and need for two parameters as output - graph and library - which are later used to run the graph or create a graph runtime ?

For example in this code :

```
opt_level = 3
target = tvm.target.cuda()
with relay.build_config(opt_level=opt_level):
    graph, lib, params = relay.build_module.build(
        net, target, params=params)
```

What are the outputs **graph**, **lib** ?
Can we use just **one** of them to generate a graph runtime or do we always have to use both of them like below :

```
# create random input
ctx = tvm.gpu()
data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=data_shape).astype("float32")
# create module
module = graph_runtime.create(graph, lib, ctx)
# set input and parameters
module.set_input("data", data)
module.set_input(**params)
# run
module.run()
# get output
out = module.get_output(0, tvm.nd.empty(out_shape)).asnumpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a graph runtime you always need both **graph** and **lib**.

- **graph**: the execution graph in json format
- **lib**: the TVM module library of compiled functions specifically for this graph on the target hardware.

In other words, **graph** tells the compiler how the layers are arranged; **lib** specifies the function each layer implements.

Source: https://docs.tvm.ai/tutorials/relay_quick_start.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-relay-quick-start-py